# Connecting to SQL Server to run a procedure

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to connect to SQL Server to call a procedure that was set up for me that I will be filling and updating a table I already have. I don't know how to go about connecting or linking to a external server. I do everything in MySqlWorkbench.

How to I start this please?

Thanks
Keith

Comment: Is it SQL Server (OR) MySQL?

Comment: I'm not familiar with MySqlWorkbench, but I don't think it can connect to SQL Server in the way you suggest. It looks to me as if the only thing it can do with SQL Server is translate a database from there to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect to `SQL Server` then you can get help from using `SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)`. If you have installed SQL Server on your machine then probably SSMS has already been installed in your machine. Else you can use the SQL Server installer and just install client tool which include SSMS; using which you can connect to any SQL Server instance inside/outside your network.

Here is a download link for the same but it's a express version http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=8961